# Tool that would show all semantic data contained in a given web page

Tags: facebook-opengraph, semantic-web, semantic-markup, microformats, rdfs

I'm looking for a web service, browser extension, or anything else that directly extracts any and all semantic data contained in a given web page, as long as that semantic data is following any of the myriad of modern standards used for embedding semantic information inside web pages. Somehow I couldn't find anything that works. I could find many 'semantic crawlers' but no tool that just shows what semantic data you have at hand on a given web page.

I'd be very glad getting pointers to any such tool, if one exists out there.
I can't fathom how people debug or develop their semantic harvesters without it.......

I listed some of the relevant standards as the tags for this question (see question's tags which usually show here below) but this list is not to be taken as exhaustive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some good starting points, you might consider:

- [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)
- [RDFa Play](http://rdfa.info/play/) (More of a testbed, but nice visuals)
- [GetSchema.org](http://getschema.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- Apache's [Any23.org](http://any23.org/)
- [Sindice](http://www.sindice.com/)

Sindice is perhaps the most general of these, most of the others focus on RDFa (my own bias, sorry).  Your choice might depend a bit on what you consider semantic data (e.g. do you want HTML5 semantics like `<title>` to count?  For just RDFa I have found Apache's Any23 best for my needs, with nice API, flexible formats and accurate extraction.

Good question though, I'd be curious to see what tools others most recommend.  W3C has a [longer list](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SemanticWebTools#Semantic_Web_Browsers) that may be slightly dated.

Comment: Thanks @cboettig, I'm learning those. It seems Sindice is a semantic search engine (and a very convenient one as far as I can see first off) rather than something where semantic data can be extracted from a specified url or html, although maybe there's some clever way to make it also do the later(?). Those are great resources and I'm learning them more carefully now. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I will probably post a similar question about open-source code for parsing out the same, although some of these tools here are possibly already relying on just that.

Comment: @matt Sindice has an inspector tool, sorry I didn't provide a direct link: http://inspector.sindice.com/ It's not as robust/thorough as the Any23.org in my experience.  Correct, it also has a semantic search engine.

Comment: inspector.sindice.com does so far seem to be one of the best in terms of usage experience - very responsive and has many of the necessary conveniences included. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Yandex has [tool](http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml) for validating embedded semantic markup as well. There is some [doc](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1127819) available also. It works with microdata, schema.org, opengraph, rdfa, microformats. Not just with microformats, as you may conclude from title :)

If you're looking for opensource tools there is mighty library [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib) on Github. It does a lot and parsing in particular.

> The library contains parsers and serializers for RDF/XML, N3, NTriples, N-Quads, Turtle, TriX, RDFa and Microdata.

Answer (score 0):

For RDF data, there is Tim Berners-Lee’s [Tabulator](http://www.w3.org/2005/ajar/tab). A browser available as web app (resp. FLOSS JavaScript) and Firefox add-on. Howver, it seems no longer to be maintained (?).

For RDFa, there is the Firefox add-on [RDFa Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rdfa-developer/).

For RDF files linked in the page’s head, there is the Firefox-addon [Semantic Radar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/semantic-radar/).

Another Firefox add-on is [OpenLink Data Explorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/openlink-data-explorer/).

Comment: I've used OpenLink Data Explorer's Chrome extension before, and within my limitations couldn't figure what it's doing, not to mention I found its presentation style somewhat intriguing... Maybe it's just me..... I'm still learning the relationships between all those standards and formats, which is a topic for orthogonal research for me.